# python pass struct and pointer to c function for input and output

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I do as follows,but get error.

Is there anythong wrong in using ctypes, or something wrong in types of parameters I pass?

I think there may be three points should be thought about:

1. Generate right parameters passed to c function in python.
2. Pass pointer with the type of struct to c function.
3. Right instantiate struct depend on the  given array, if need struct in python code.

I'm new for c, especially pointer.

c code:the struct,    ansfer.h

```
typedef unsigned char boolean_T;


struct emxArray_real_T
{


    double *data;
    int *size;
    int allocatedSize;
    int numDimensions;
    boolean_T canFreeData;
};
```

the function called by python,  ansfer.c

```
void ansferA(const emxArray_real_T *dataArray, double H, emxArray_real_T *TE,
                 emxArray_real_T *Lag)
{

...

P2 += dataArray->data[a + dataArray->size[0] * b];

...

TE->data[a + TE->size[0] * b] = te;

Lag->data[a + Lag->size[0] * b] = h;

...
}
```

then，`gcc -o libansfer.so -shared -fPIC *.c`

libansfer.so is generated.

I rewrite the test.py according to the advices. Add structs as follows.

python code :test.py

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes

c_double_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)
c_int_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)

class emxArray_real_T(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("data",          c_double_p),  
        ("size",          c_int_p), 
        ("allocatedSize", ctypes.c_int),
        ("numDimensions", ctypes.c_int),
        ("canFreeData",   ctypes.c_bool)
    ]

indata = np.array([[1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1],[2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2],[3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,2.2,2.2,2.2]])

LL, CC = indata.shape 

TE = np.zeros((LL,LL), dtype=np.double)
Lag = np.zeros((LL,LL), dtype=np.double)

SS = np.array([LL, CC])
instruct = emxArray_real_T()
instruct.data = c_double_p(ctypes.c_double(indata.ctypes.data))
instruct.size = c_int_p(ctypes.c_int(SS.ctypes.data))
instruct.allocatedSize = ctypes.c_int(LL*CC)
instruct.numDimensions = ctypes.c_int(2)
instruct.canFreeData = ctypes.c_bool(0)

ss = np.array([LL, LL])
outstruct1 = emxArray_real_T()
outstruct1.data = c_double_p(ctypes.c_double(TE.ctypes.data))
outstruct1.size = c_int_p(ctypes.c_int(ss.ctypes.data))
outstruct1.allocatedSize = ctypes.c_int(LL*LL)
outstruct1.numDimensions = ctypes.c_int(2)
outstruct1.canFreeData = ctypes.c_bool(0)

outstruct2 = emxArray_real_T()
outstruct2.data = c_double_p(ctypes.c_double(Lag.ctypes.data))
outstruct2.size = c_int_p(ctypes.c_int(ss.ctypes.data))
outstruct2.allocatedSize = ctypes.c_int(LL*LL)
outstruct2.numDimensions = ctypes.c_int(2)
outstruct2.canFreeData = ctypes.c_bool(0)

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libansfer.so')

lib.ansferA(instruct,ctypes.c_double(3), outstruct1, outstruct2)
```

---

but similar error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\testfile\test.py", line 106, in <module>
    lib.ansferA(instruct,ctypes.c_double(3), outstruct1, outstruct2)
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: The code shown is both unreadable and incomplete. Please take time to proof read, format your question  properly and provide a [mcve].

Comment: The C appears to require pointers to `struct emxArray_real_T` as the rightmost two arguments, but you are passing pointers to doubles.  You need to describe the struct to ctypes.  It is probably crashing when it tried to access one of the members that are pointers.

Comment: `byref(ctypes.c_double(indata.ctypes.data))` takes `data` ("a pointer to the memory area of the array as a Python integer"), then casts that to a `double` (_not_ a double pointer!) then takes a pointer to that double. `indata.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))` would work instead instead, but look at what cdarke wrote about structs.

Comment: @cdarke "describe the struct to ctypes",could you tell in detail? I just find some simple examples,  but don't know how to describe the struct to ctypes here because the struct has a double array pointer, and a int array pointer.

Comment: @glen:  I'm working on a struct class for you, but I need to know what a `boolean_T` is.  It is not a standard C type so far as I know,  `int` or `_Bool`?

Comment: @DavidW I learn more from you about "byref", thank you very much. I'll try as you and cdarke adviced, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but formatting rules do not allow me to place this as a comment (and still be readable).

The struct will look something like this:

```
c_double_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)
c_int_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)

class emxArray_real_T(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("data",          c_double_p),  
        ("size",          c_int_p), 
        ("allocatedSize", ctypes.c_int),
        ("numDimensions", ctypes.c_int),
        ("canFreeData",   ctypes.c_bool)
    ]
```

I has to guess with the type of `canFreeData`, `boolean_T` is not a standard C type.

Then initialise the struct with something like:

```
emxArray_struct = emxArray_real_T( insert values here as parameters )
```

I have not worked with numpy, so I don't know if/how its types are mapped to ctypes or to regular python variable types.